# Antlr4 match Cyrillic, Latin, Polish and Greek Letters plus special characters?

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

In Antlr4 grammar I need to match with the help of Regular Expressions Latin,Cyrillic,Polish and Greek Letters plus special characters. This is what I have:

```
STRING: ['][\p{L} 0-9\[\]\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\\~`\!@#%&\-_+={}""<>:;,\/°]*['];
```

So I am saying that a `String` starts and ends with `''`. Inside I can have any letter (`\p{L}`), number and special character except from `'`. I have tested this on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and it exactly what I want. But in Antlr4 it is not working. Instead the closest thing I get is:

```
['][a-zA-Z0-9 \[\]\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\\~`\!@#%&\-_+={}""<>:;,\/°]*[']
```

But the Problem is that something like `'Ąłćórżnęł'` won't be accepted in my language, but it should be.

Am I doing something wrong in Antlr4 or is that a limitation ? How could I manage to get it to work in Antlr4 ? String is a Lexer Rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\p{L}` is not supported by ANTLR. You will have to write these ranges out by hand like this: `[\u1234-\u5678]` (change `\u....` with your hexadecimal Unicode points), where `\u1234` is the start of the range and `\u5678` the end. Note that you can put more than 1 range in your character set: `[\u1234-\u1238\u3456-\u5679]`.

> Thanks, but how about a regular expression in Antlr4 where I allow everything inside of a String except a character like '. But I say that a string start with and end with '

That would look like this:

```
STRING : '\'' ~[']* '\'';
```

and with escaped quotes and not allowing line breaks, do this:

```
STRING : '\'' ( ~['\r\n] | '\\' ['\\] )* '\'';
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about a regular expression in Antlr4 where I allow everything inside of a String except a character like '. But I say that a string start with and end with '  ?

Comment: Thanks. In Antlr4 I did it like this: STRING: ['] (~['] | '\'\'')* ['];

Comment: The funny thing is that I came up with the solution by looking at the link below. I just now realized that it was you too who implemented the tiny-language-antlr4 Gramar  :) 
https://github.com/bkiers/tiny-language-antlr4/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/tl/antlr4/TL.g4